# Why df -h is showing wrong size in raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I installed the Raspbian Jessie Lite in a 8gb SDCard using the `Win32 Disk Imager` to mount and using the `Sd Formatter` to format the sd. 
After i mount it and put on my Raspberry, when i enter `df -h` it shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       1.3G  931M  262M  79% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M   12M  451M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   20M   41M  34% /boot
```

Where are the remaining free space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should expand the filesystem after your first boot into Raspbian. You can do this by running `sudo raspi-config` from the command line (terminal). In Jessie there is also a menu option under Preferences that allows you to get into a graphical interface for the Raspi-config command, which also allows you to expand the filesystem to use the full card.

The filesystem is deliberately small so that the image you use to create the disk is not unnecessarily large, and to make sure the image works on any size SD card (as long as it is bigger than the original image size).

Comment: It works, but do you know where i can do this without the raspi-config, come file that writes on it?

Comment: @ggui You can do this manually with `fdisk` and `resize2fs` but the inputs you need are long, complex and error prone (and vary depending on how you have installed Raspbian).

Comment: i had similar problem, if I try rasp-config > advanced option > expand filesystem, I get error message saying `sda2 is not on SD card. Don't know how to expand`